# Salesforce Formula Explanation

Tags: formula, formula-field

I cant understand the below Salesforce Formula. Could someone help me to understand this?

```
IF ( ISBLANK(Actual_Finish_Date__c), 
Deadline__c - IF(ISBLANK( 
Actual_Start_Date__c), Kickoff__c, 
Actual_Start_Date__c ) + 1, 
Actual_Finish_Date__c - IF(ISBLANK( 
Actual_Start_Date__c), Kickoff__c , 
Actual_Start_Date__c )+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

> IF(*logical_test*, *value_if_true*, *value_if_false*)
> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given value if true and another value if false

> ISBLANK(*expression*)
> Determines if an expression has a value and returns TRUE if it does not. If it contains a value, this function returns FALSE.

Assuming that `Deadline__c`, `Kickoff__c`, `Actual_Start_Date__c` and `Actual_Finish_Date__c` are Date fields

```
IF(
    ISBLANK( Actual_Start_Date__c ),
    Kickoff__c,
    Actual_Start_Date__c
)
```

This formula check whether `Actual_Start_Date__c` hasn't a value, if so returns the value of `Kickoff__c`, otherwise the one of `Actual_Start_Date__c`
E.G.

| `Actual_Start_Date__c` | `Kickoff__c` | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 |

```
IF( ISBLANK(Actual_Finish_Date__c),
    Deadline__c -
    IF(
        ISBLANK( Actual_Start_Date__c),
        Kickoff__c,
        Actual_Start_Date__c
    )
    + 1,
    Actual_Finish_Date__c -
    IF( ISBLANK( Actual_Start_Date__c),
        Kickoff__c,
        Actual_Start_Date__c
    )
    +1
)
```

If `Actual_Finish_Date__c` is null, it returns the days between `Deadline__c` and `Kickoff__c` plus one if `Actual_Start_Date__c` is null,
or the days between `Deadline__c` and `Actual_Start_Date__c` plus one if the latter isn't null.
If `Actual_Finish_Date__c` isn't null, it return the days between `Actual_Finish_Date__c` and `Kickoff__c` plus one if `Actual_Start_Date__c` is null,
or the days between `Actual_Finish_Date__c` and `Actual_Start_Date__c` plus one if the latter isn't null.

| `Actual_Finish_Date__c` | `Deadline__c` | `Actual_Start_Date__c` | `Kickoff__c` | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2020-01-10 | null | 2020-01-02 | 9 |
| 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-10 | null | 2020-01-02 | 19 |
| null | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-02 | 6 |
| 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-02 | 16 |

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

This formula could have been written as:

```
BLANKVALUE(Actual_Finish_Date__c, Deadline__c) - 
BLANKVALUE(Actual_Start_Date__c, Kickoff__c) + 1
```

This should make it easier to understand. We want to calculate the number of days between two dates. We'll take either the Actual Finish Date or the Deadline (if no Finish Date is provided), and subtract the Actual Start Date or the Kickoff Date (if no Start Date is provided).

The subtraction of two dates results in a number for the number of days between the two. We then add 1 day to count the start date to get the proper count (e.g. if you start today and end today, it took you one day to complete the project).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!!